# grunt-contrib-uglify fails invalid syntax for binary number

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

When I try to uglify a JS-File I get this message:

'Invalid syntax: 0b00000001'

Is there an option that uglify can handle binary numbers?